# Redirect Loop for Google Account login with SSL for Custom Domain on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, redirect-loop

I have setup SSL (VIP) for a custom domain on my Google App Engine app (https://www.gqueues.com).

Everything works fine for most of my users.  There are no problems at all for users who login with their Google Apps accounts (which uses OpenId).  Most users who login with their Google Accounts don't have any problems either.

HOWEVER, a handful of Google Account users get a redirect loop error

(ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS) like the image below when they attempt to login.

[image: redirectLoop]

This is the code I'm using to create the login url.  It's worked fine for the last 3 years, and the only thing that has changed is that it now goes to https instead of http:

```
loginURL = users.create_login_url("https://www.gqueues.com/main")
```

The *main* page has login required:

```
@login_required
def get(self):
```

I am unable to reproduce the redirect loop with any of my test accounts or machines.  However, one of my users reported that it seemed to be looping between these two addresses:

```
https://appengine.google.com/_ah/loginform?state=xxxxxxxxxxx
https://www.gqueues.com/_ah/conflogin?state=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

On some other SO posts about redirect loops people suggest that some of these auth pages are getting cached, but I've checked and all of them use a 302 redirect which doesn't get cached.

[image: Imgur]

Also, I've had the users with the issue clear their browser cache and cookies and make sure they are NOT blocking third-party cookies, but none of this helps.  The problem occurs on various browsers and operating systems, so I don't think it pertains to a particular setup.

The only thing that works is to have the users with the problem access my app on the appspot address:
https://gqueues-hrd.appspot.com

This of course is not really a solution at all.  The reason I'm spending thousands of dollars for the SSL certificate and VIP on GAE is so that everything the user sees is on my custom domain (and so that I'm using my own certificate and not some shared one from Google).

Does anyone (particularly from the App Engine team) have any idea what's going on?  It seems like the issue is somewhere in the Google Account login code implemented in App Engine or perhaps with the new SSL for custom domains code.

Thanks much,

Cameron

Comment: does it happen only on SSL? does SSL got anything to do with the problem?

Comment: It happens to me sometimes with android browser. But you fixed it because I got your newsletter ?

Comment: This is still very much a real problem.  Can someone from the Google App Engine team please comment/investigate?  @ShayErlichmen Yes, it has to do with GAE's implementation of SSL for Custom Domains, but the issue happens regardless of whether HTTPS is being used to access the app.

The issue first arose once I activated SSL for custom domains and updated the CNAME record to point to the VIP address-  _before_ I changed the code to use HTTPS.  So the issue seems to have to do with how GAE implements VIP on the backend and how this interacts with authentication provided by GAE Users API.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response on this. Can you think of any condition specific to failing users? How many are they? Do all of them have @gmail.com account? Do they multi-login? Can you provide an example of actual occurrence with specific google account and the time?

Comment: Thanks for replying @TakashiMatsuo.  I was beginning to worry no one was out there! Are no other apps experiencing this issue?  I guess there probably aren't too many App Engine apps that are using the custom SSL with the Users API for login.  Anyway, here is the info and clues I've been gathering about the problem:

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo  
  
1. I think the condition for failing users has something to do with the approval that gets cached for 30 days.  When a person logs in for the very first time they can check the box that says "Remember this approval for the next 30 days" as in this image: http://i.imgur.com/Ab5jo.png .  This apparently is cached in servers on Google's side, because cookies can be cleared and the approval is still remembered.  But I'm wondering if there is some mix up between a cached approval for the HTTP address and the HTTPS address.

Comment: Perhaps when they login it grabs the token from the cache for the HTTP site, but since they are at the HTTPS address authorization fails, so it goes back to check for a cached token, returns the HTTP one and just ends up in this infinite redirect loop.

Comment: 2. This problem is affecting only @gmail.com accounts. Google Apps accounts never experience this issue (I use a separate OpenID authentication for them).  It's affecting 100s of my users - which is a very very small percentage - but for those 100s of users its a VERY big deal, because they can't login and access their data in GQueues.

Comment: 3. Yes, I believe many of them have multi-login enabled.  One guy who was experiencing the redirect loop was able to break out of it by logging in to multiple Gmail accounts in the same browser.  Then when he attempted to login to GQueues instead of going into the redirect loop it took him to the screen where he was prompted to choose which account he wanted to use to login to GQueues as in this image: http://i.imgur.com/0birP.png  Once he chose the account and said allow it allowed him to login without the redirect loop.

Comment: 4. I have a different app (APPID: eos-hrd) which has activated custom SSL on GAE but is not currently using HTTPS when users access the site.  However, there are users of that app that are also experiencing the redirect issue.  So the problem seems to be related to the using the VIP and the new CNAME record and not to the code or actually using HTTPS.

Comment: 5. Also in case it's relevant, a year ago both of these apps (gqueues-hrd and eos-hrd) were migrated from apps that were using the master/slave datastore - so aliases were setup from their master/slave APPIDs (gqueues and etsybs) to their HRD APPIDs as part of the migration tool process.

Comment: 6. I will email you privately with email addresses of customer's who have experienced this issue.  

Thanks so much for taking a look at the problem!  -Cameron Henneke

Comment: Thanks for the info. We're looking into this.

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo Terrific, and thanks so much, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo My continued experimentation raises this question:

Are there different authTokens for access to secure and unsecured addresses?  If so, maybe there is a mixup between the two that's contributing to the problem?

I've found that going here succeeds (notice the continue param is HTTPS):

https://www.gqueues.com/_ah/login?continue=https://www.gqueues.com/main&auth=REALLY_LONG_AUTH_TOKEN

While going here redirects to an account login page (notice the continue param is HTTP):

https://www.gqueues.com/_ah/login?continue=http://www.gqueues.com/main&auth=SAME_REALLY_LONG_AUTH_TOKEN

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo  Well that didn't print well.  

This link succeeds (notice the continue param is HTTPS):    

`https://www.gqueues.com/_ah/login?continue=https://www.gqueues.com/main&auth=REALLY_LONG_AUTH_TOKEN`  
  

While going here redirects to an account login page (notice the continue param is HTTP):  
  

`https://www.gqueues.com/_ah/login?continue=http://www.gqueues.com/main&auth=SAME_REALLY_LONG_AUTH_TOKEN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We think we've identified the problem on the App Engine side and we're working on a fix. Thanks!

Comment: Have you guys had a chance yet to make any progress on this fix?  Any chance it will go out with this month's AppEngine update?